# my phone, Galaxy S4, was hacked. and now I think it's affected my app permissions by adding files to them?

Tags: applications, file-permissions

My partner and I had our phones hacked recently. He was able to prevent any real damage from happening. But he reset his just in case. I wanted to go through my phone first, to see what had been affected. I noticed that most of my apps looked like they had been changed. There were a lot of things added to the list of permissions that the app and all related apps were granted. It just didn't seem like they were legit. I tried resetting app preferences and I dogs a factory reset and the apps are still like that. I don't know how to change it, or if I even need to. https://www.dropbox.com/sc/fnvxs9qwp2upwxo/AAAuhCphY2CMqC0EMVIJibX_a

Comment: Could someone with Dropbox access integrate that screenshot (I assume it is one) properly, please? Some people (e.g. me) cannot see it due to firewalling ;)

Answer (score 0):

Granting other apps permissions does absolutely nothing unless those apps are designed to take advantage of those permissions.  It is unlikely that stock Android and Samsung apps are maliciously cooperating with this malware.

There is also nothing abnormal about the permissions in that screenshot.

Comment: That group of permissions wasn't there before tho, which is why I thought they might be malicious. And  basically every app on my phone has those permissions. Along with the permissions that were originally granted. So between the originals and the add-ons, most of the apps in my phone have access to evvveryyythiiiiing. Because somehow, all of these apps are related. There's a huge list at the top of permissions that names every app with those permissions. That list wasn't there before.

Comment: Is it possible for someone with access to my phone and accounts, etc, to be able to add those permissions?

Comment: Possibly.  But again they can't do anything, adding permissions to an app doesn't rewrite the app to use those permissions.

Comment: @MatthewRead taking into consideration the `.apk`s might have been replaced by "hacked variants", those apps might well take advantage of "additional permissions". Though I've never heard of such an hacking attack, that doesn't mean it's impossible – though I agree highly unlikely. Safest way is factory-reset and "clean install" of apps needed – even safer re-flashing the ROM first.